# The route_xxx methods such as route_method have been deprecated... (Grape API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, deprecated, ruby-grape

I have a rake task to list my Grape api routes. When I run it, I get:

```
% bundle exec rake api:routes
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:7: The route_xxx methods such as route_method have been deprecated, please use request_method.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:8: The route_xxx methods such as route_path have been deprecated, please use path.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:9: The route_xxx methods such as route_version have been deprecated, please use version.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:9: The route_xxx methods such as route_version have been deprecated, please use version.
     GET        /api/widget/color(.:format)
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:7: The route_xxx methods such as route_method have been deprecated, please use request_method.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:8: The route_xxx methods such as route_path have been deprecated, please use path.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:9: The route_xxx methods such as route_version have been deprecated, please use version.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:9: The route_xxx methods such as route_version have been deprecated, please use version.
     GET        /api/widget/flavor(.:format)
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:7: The route_xxx methods such as route_method have been deprecated, please use request_method.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:8: The route_xxx methods such as route_path have been deprecated, please use path.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:9: The route_xxx methods such as route_version have been deprecated, please use version.
/Users/private/my_project/lib/tasks/api/routes.rake:9: The route_xxx methods such as route_version have been deprecated, please use version.
     POST       /api/widget/order(.:format)

...repeat x100...
```

My rake task:

```
namespace :api do
  desc 'API Routes'
  task routes: :environment do
    MyApi.routes.each do |api|
      method = api.route_method || '??'
      path = api.route_path || '--'
      path = path.gsub(':version', api.route_version) if path && api.route_version
      puts "     #{method.ljust(10)} #{path}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the methods as suggested in the deprecation warnings:

```
namespace :api do
  desc 'API Routes'
  task routes: :environment do
    Alex::Base.routes.each do |api|
      method = api.request_method || '??'
      path = api.path || '--'
      path = path.gsub(':version', api.version) if path && api.version
      puts "     #{method.ljust(10)} #{path}"
    end
  end
end
```

Voila! No more warnings:

```
bundle exec rake api:routes
     GET        /api/widget/color(.:format)
     GET        /api/widget/flavor(.:format)
     POST       /api/widget/order(.:format)
...etc...
```